# Hibernate Entity Circular Reference Produces StackOverflowError

Tags: java, hibernate

### The Problem

I get a `StackOverflowError` when attempting to have an `Order` which references a `Product`, and a `Product` that references an `Order`. I know this is due to having a circular reference, but I am unsure as to how to fix it. I'm new to ORMs but not to SQL/Schema Design: typically, I would have a `Ordered_Products` table which maps an `Order` to a `Product`, but I thought Hibernate would automagically take care of that for me.

`Product`s all have unique IDs (these are generated outside the app), so no two `Product`s are the same. `Order` IDs are also generated outside the app (I will be importing this data from a CSV in an earlier process in this pipeline).

Could someone assist with moving forward?

### The Models

#### Order.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
class Order implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2916987431893884948L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="contactName")
    private String contactName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Product> products;

    // ...plain old getters and setters omitted...

    public Set<Product> getProducts() {

        // Should this be done at the member variable declaration?
        if (null == products) {
            this.products = new HashSet<Product>();
        }

        return products;
    }

    public void addProduct(Product p) {
        p.setOrder(this);
        getProducts().add(p);
    }

    public String toString() { 
    /* plain old to String which prints all member vars */ 
    }
}
```

#### Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 663408095532480033L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="size")
    private Size size;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable=false)
    private Order order;

    // ...plain old getters and setters...

    public enum Size {
        EMPTY,
        XXSMALL,
        XSMALL,
        SMALL,
        MEDIUM,
        LARGE
    }

    public String toString() { 
    /* plain old to String which prints all member vars */ 
    }
}
```

### The Code That Produces the Error

```
Product b = new Product();
b.setId("ABC123");
b.setSize(Product.Size.LARGE);

Product c = new Product();
c.setId("DEF456");
c.setSize(Product.Size.XSMALL);

Order o = new Order();
o.setId(551234L);
o.setContactName("Marco");
o.addProduct(b);
o.addProduct(c);
System.out.println("Order ID=" + o);
```

### The Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.<init>(HashMap.java:1451)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeySet.iterator(HashMap.java:912)
    at java.util.HashSet.iterator(HashSet.java:172)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:454)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.code4armour.shippingtracker.ui.model.Order.toString(Order.java:207)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.code4armour.shippingtracker.ui.model.Band.toString(Band.java:78)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:462)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.code4armour.shippingtracker.ui.model.Order.toString(Order.java:207)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
    at com.code4armour.shippingtracker.ui.model.Band.toString(Band.java:78)
```

The problem here is the `Order.toString()` calling the `Product.toString()`, and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider a managing class/object which contains instance(s) of both. Through this you could call both `toString()` methods separately and safely.

**Edit** (continuing from my first comment):

Order_Product_Link (table)

- OrderID (FK)
- ProductID (FK)

Constraints:
- the **combination** of orderID and productID should be unique

Considerations:

- ensure a cascading delete. So if you delete a product entry, all entries in Order_Product_Link referencing its ID need to be deleted. However you most likely won't want the order deleted. And vice versa.

Comment: This is how I would do it in traditional Schema design, ie: an `Ordered_Products` table, which ties an order to a product (multiple rows in this table would signify multiple products tied to one order) For some reason I thought Hibernate would do this for me by creating that OneToMany and OneToOne relation. Could you advise how to create this managing class?

Comment: Hi. Sure. I can go into more detail later when I'm free. For now I would recommend considering a "linking" table. My usual naming convention for these is "table1_table2_link". So in this case "Order_Product_Link". This table would have 2 columns. A foreign key to each original table. If an order contain 2 products. There will be 2 entries in this new table. Each containing the unique product ids. Both having the same order I'd.

Comment: @MarcoPietroCirillo Any luck?

Comment: I understand the concept, it's `Hibernate`s syntax that confuses me. I've marked your answer as correct, I may put my syntax problems in a new question

Answer (score 2):

> The problem here is the Order.toString() calling the Product.toString(), and vice versa

You have identified the problem, it is pretty clear why you are getting `StackOverflowError`. Just don't call one's entity `toString()` from another entity's `toString()`.