# CommunicationsException and StackOverflowError when using save() method of CRUD repository with bi-direction relationship

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I use spring-data-jpa, hibernate with mysql server. My model have relationship like this : A Project have many Job, A Job have many TechnicalRequirement, LanguageRequirement. When I try to update Project with method save() of repository (with modify Job and Requirement in it). It cause CommunicationsException:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 85 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 77 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3562) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3462) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3903) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2530) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4796) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(ProxyConnection.java:388) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(HikariProxyConnection.java) [HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.resetConnection(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:101) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.afterCompletion(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:268) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:125) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:294) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:139) [hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doRollback(JpaTransactionManager.java:559) [spring-orm-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:838) [spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:812) [spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:551) [spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:298) [spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) [spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) [spring-tx-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) [spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) [spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) [spring-aop-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.save(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at fa.mksgroup.si.service.impl.MatchedTechSkillServiceImpl.add(MatchedTechSkillServiceImpl.java:53) [classes/:na]
    at fa.mksgroup.si.controller.ProjectController.addProject(ProjectController.java:256) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:97) [cas-client-core-3.5.1.jar:3.5.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3014) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3472) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    ... 128 common frames omitted
```

and this StackOverflowError:

```
2019-04-22 18:35:51.321 ERROR 17907 --- [nio-9000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError] with root cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at sun.security.provider.DigestBase.engineUpdate(DigestBase.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineUpdate(MessageDigest.java:584) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.security.MessageDigest.update(MessageDigest.java:325) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.HmacCore.engineUpdate(HmacCore.java:166) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_201]
    at javax.crypto.Mac.update(Mac.java:510) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.security.ssl.MAC.compute(MAC.java:135) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.encrypt(OutputRecord.java:237) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(SSLSocketImpl.java:862) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:850) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3731) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2512) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2486) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1966) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar:5.1.46]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2167) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4269) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

I faced this error one time and the only way I know is use many for and save it one by one.Is there other way to slove this problem, cause it take too many line of code to replace the only one save() method?

Edit: 
This is my entities:

```
@Entity(name = "project")
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    private static final int MAX10 = 10;
    private static final int MAX50 = 50;
    private static final int MAX100 = 100;
    private static final int MAX300 = 300;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = MAX100)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "company", nullable = false)
    private String company;

    @Column(name = "teamsize")
    private int teamsize;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "timestart", nullable = false)
    private String timestart;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "timeend", nullable = false)
    private String timeend;

    @Size(max = MAX300)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "techskills")
    private String techskills;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "createBy", nullable = false)
    private Long createBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name = "modifyBy")
    private Long modifyBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "modifyDate")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "lastLoad", nullable = false)
    private String lastLoad;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Job.class, mappedBy = "project", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Job> jobs;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public int getTeamsize() {
        return teamsize;
    }

    public void setTeamsize(int teamsize) {
        this.teamsize = teamsize;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTechskills() {
        return techskills;
    }

    public void setTechskills(String techskills) {
        this.techskills = techskills;
    }

    public Long getCreateBy() {
        return createBy;
    }

    public void setCreateBy(Long createBy) {
        this.createBy = createBy;
    }

    public String getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Long getModifyBy() {
        return modifyBy;
    }

    public void setModifyBy(Long modifyBy) {
        this.modifyBy = modifyBy;
    }

    public String getModifyDate() {
        return modifyDate;
    }

    public void setModifyDate(String modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }

    public String getLastLoad() {
        return lastLoad;
    }

    public void setLastLoad(String lastLoad) {
        this.lastLoad = lastLoad;
    }

    public Set<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void setJobs(Set<Job> jobs) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getTimestart() {
        return timestart;
    }

    public void setTimestart(String timestart) {
        this.timestart = timestart;
    }

    public String getTimeend() {
        return timeend;
    }

    public void setTimeend(String timeend) {
        this.timeend = timeend;
    }

}

@Entity(name = "job")
@Table(name = "job")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id", scope = Job.class)
public class Job {
    private static final int MAX10 = 10;
    private static final int MAX50 = 50;
    private static final int MAX300 = 300;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = MAX300)
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Size(max = MAX300)
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false)
    private String role;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "timestart", nullable = false)
    private String timestart;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "timeend", nullable = false)
    private String timeend;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "createBy", nullable = false)
    private Long createBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name = "modifyBy")
    private Long modifyBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "modifyDate")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "lastLoad", nullable = false)
    private String lastLoad;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Candidate.class, mappedBy = "pk.job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Candidate> candidates;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectid")
    private Project project;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedCertificate.class, mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MatchedCertificate> matchedCertificates;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedLanguage.class, mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MatchedLanguage> matchedLanguages ;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedTechSkill.class, mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MatchedTechSkill> matchedTechSkills;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getTimestart() {
        return timestart;
    }

    public void setTimestart(String timestart) {
        this.timestart = timestart;
    }

    public String getTimeend() {
        return timeend;
    }

    public void setTimeend(String timeend) {
        this.timeend = timeend;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Long getCreateBy() {
        return createBy;
    }

    public void setCreateBy(Long createBy) {
        this.createBy = createBy;
    }

    public String getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(String createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Long getModifyBy() {
        return modifyBy;
    }

    public void setModifyBy(Long modifyBy) {
        this.modifyBy = modifyBy;
    }

    public String getModifyDate() {
        return modifyDate;
    }

    public void setModifyDate(String modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }

    public String getLastLoad() {
        return lastLoad;
    }

    public void setLastLoad(String lastLoad) {
        this.lastLoad = lastLoad;
    }

    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public void setCandidates(Set<Candidate> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }

    public void setProject(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }


    public Set<MatchedCertificate> getMatchedCertificates() {
        return matchedCertificates;
    }

    public void setMatchedCertificates(Set<MatchedCertificate> matchedCertificates) {
        this.matchedCertificates = matchedCertificates;
    }

    public Set<MatchedLanguage> getMatchedLanguages() {
        return matchedLanguages;
    }

    public void setMatchedLanguages(Set<MatchedLanguage> matchedLanguages) {
        this.matchedLanguages = matchedLanguages;
    }

    public Set<MatchedTechSkill> getMatchedTechSkills() {
        return matchedTechSkills;
    }

    public void setMatchedTechSkills(Set<MatchedTechSkill> matchedTechSkills) {
        this.matchedTechSkills = matchedTechSkills;
    }

    public Job() {
    }

    public Job(@Size(max = 300) String description, @Size(max = 300) String role, @Size(max = 10) String timestart,
            @Size(max = 10) String timeend, @Size(max = 10) String status, Long createBy,
            @Size(max = 10) String createDate, Long modifyBy, @Size(max = 10) String modifyDate,
            @Size(max = 50) String lastLoad) {
        super();
        this.description = description;
        this.role = role;
        this.timestart = timestart;
        this.timeend = timeend;
        this.status = status;
        this.createBy = createBy;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.modifyBy = modifyBy;
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
        this.lastLoad = lastLoad;
    }

}

@Entity(name = "matchedcertificate")
@Table(name = "matchedcertificate")
@Data
public class MatchedCertificate {

    private static final int MAX10 = 10;
    private static final int MAX50 = 50;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "score")
    private float score;

    @Column(name = "createBy", nullable = false)
    private Long createBy;


    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name = "modifyBy")
    private Long modifyBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "modifyDate")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "lastLoad", nullable = false)
    private String lastLoad;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobid")
    private Job job;

}

@Entity(name = "matchedlanguage")
@Table(name = "matchedlanguage")
@Data
public class MatchedLanguage {

    private static final int MAX10 = 10;
    private static final int MAX20 = 20;
    private static final int MAX50 = 50;
    private static final int MAX100 = 100;
    private static final int MAX300 = 300;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "level", length = 5, nullable = false)
    private int level;

    @Min(1950)
    @Column(name = "lastused")
    private int lastused;

    @Column(name = "createBy", nullable = false)
    private Long createBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name = "modifyBy")
    private Long modifyBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "modifyDate")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "lastLoad", nullable = false)
    private String lastLoad;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobid")
    private Job job;
}
@Entity(name = "matchedtechskill")
@Table(name = "matchedtechskill")
@Data
public class MatchedTechSkill {

    private static final int MAX10 = 10;
    private static final int MAX50 = 50;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "level", length = 10, nullable = false)
    private int level;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "experience")
    private String experience;

    @Min(1950)
    @Column(name = "lastused")
    private int lastused;

    @Column(name = "createBy", nullable = false)
    private Long createBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "createDate", nullable = false)
    private String createDate;

    @Column(name = "modifyBy")
    private Long modifyBy;

    @Size(max = MAX10)
    @Column(name = "modifyDate")
    private String modifyDate;

    @Size(max = MAX50)
    @Column(name = "lastLoad", nullable = false)
    private String lastLoad;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "jobid")
    private Job job;
}
```

Comment: Can you try and use a non-SSL connection to your mysql server?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know exactly what's going on, without seeing your entities.  It's likely your entities have circular references somewhere. If you could post your entities, we could figure out which specifically is causing the issue.

See this answer [[Hibernate Entity Circular Reference Produces StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26932387/hibernate-entity-circular-reference-produces-stackoverflowerror][1])

Update after entities were added:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedCertificate.class, mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MatchedCertificate> matchedCertificates;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedLanguage.class, mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MatchedLanguage> matchedLanguages ;

@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedTechSkill.class, mappedBy = "job", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MatchedTechSkill> matchedTechSkills;
```

The mappedBy = "job" on these 3 needs to be the correct corresponding entity they are mapped to.

For example:

```
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity = MatchedCertificate.class, mappedBy = "matchedCertificate", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<MatchedCertificate> matchedCertificates;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've edited my question and add my entities.